# Coordinate ring of $X\times K$, where $X=\mathcal{V}(y^2-x^2(x+1))$ and $K$ is a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I want to show that $K[a,b,y]\subset K[x,y]$ is the coordinate ring of the affine variety $X\times K$, where $a=x^2-1$ and $b=ax$.

My thoughts are to consider the evaluation homomorphism $\varphi:K[x_1,x_2,x_3]\rightarrow K[a,b,y]$, it should be enough to show that $Ker \varphi=\mathcal{I}(X\times K)$, but i'm a bit lost on it, i guess because i don't understand well the ideal $\mathcal{I}(X\times K)$. The elements $a$ and $b$ indeed satisfy the relation given by $X$, that is, $b^2-a^2(a+1)=0$, so $(x_2^2-x_1^2(x_1+1))\subset Ker\varphi$.

Comment: With $I=(y^2-x^2(x+1))\subset K[x,y]$ then $K[x^2-1,(x^2-1)x,y]/(I\cap K[x^2-1,(x^2-1)x,y])$ is a subring of $K[x,y]/I$. What else do you want to show ?

Comment: i don't understand your point.i think i have to show that $Ker \phi \subset \mathcal{I}(X\times K)$, but the kernel seems to be larger, as $\varphi$ evaluates only at some points of the variety (those of the form $(a,b,y)$).

Comment: I don't know what you want to show. $((t^2-1)t)^2-(t^2-1)^2((t^2-1)+1)=0$ means that we have an homomorphism $K[x,y]/(y^2-x^2(x+1))\to K[t^2-1,(t^2-1)t], (x,y)\to (t^2-1,(t^2-1)t)$.

Comment: And this is an isomorphism, because $T^2-(t^2-1)^2((t^2-1)+1)$ (monic of degree 2) has to be the minimal polynomial of $(t^2-1)t$ over $K[t^2-1]$. As you see the choice of $K$ doesn't affect this.